# Mock library for Python, return value only once in mocked function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, lambda, mocking

Mocking a method with [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) is simple enough, for instance, like this:

```
    o.get_idlist = mock.Mock(return_value=[1])
```

However, that will make `get_idlist()` return `[1]` every time. Is there a way to make it return `[1]` only once, and subsequent calls return `[]` (for instance) without using `side_effect=somefun`?  I guess what I want *is* a kind of side effect, but there you go.

(I just think it's so clumsy to create a big honking named function just for that... or is there a way to use a lambda here?)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have anything against `side_effect` itself but just don't want to create a whole function, you could roughly do something like the following

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>> m = Mock()
>>> m.side_effect = [1] + [[]]*100
>>> m() 
1
>>> m()
[] 
>>> m()
[]
>>> m()
[]
>>> m()
[]
```

I admit it's a bit dirty but if you just want to make a quick test it should be sufficient. Of course you could replace [] with [0] or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do what you want with `python-mock` library is using a `side_effect`.
I can give you an alternative:

Take a look to [mockito](https://mockito-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/walk-through.html) library.
With it is easy to make what you want:

```
from mockito import when

when(o).get_idlist().thenReturn([1]).thenReturn([])
```

Comment: Aw, man, that mockito library looks pretty *awesome*. But I can't re-evaluate mocking libraries every 15 minutes, gotta do some real coding too.  :-) Maybe next project I will try out mockito. It looks like it deserves a little more fame and glory.